# How to get all values between two array values in php?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I find all values between two array items (including start and end value)?

Example:

`array('3X' => '3X','EX'=> 'EX','VG'=>'VG','G'=>'G','F'=>'F','P'=>'P')`

Input: `$arr`, `'EX'`, `'F'`

Output: `'EX', 'VG', 'G', 'F'`

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array('3X' => '3X','EX'=> 'EX','VG'=>'VG','G'=>'G','F'=>'F','P'=>'P');
$start = "3X";
$end ="F";
$new_array = [];
$i=0;$go=false;
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if($go){
        $new_array[$i] = $element; 
        $i++;
    }
    if($element==$start){
        $go = true;
    }
    if($element==$end){
        $go = false;
    }
}
$total_elems_new = count($new_array);
unset($new_array[$total_elems_new-1]);
print_r($new_array);
```

Testeed on PHP 5.6

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$arr = array('3X' => '3X','EX'=> 'EX','VG'=>'VG','G'=>'G','F'=>'F','P'=>'P');

function findValuesBetweenTwoItems($arr, $start, $end) {
  $result = [];
  $has_started = false;
  foreach ( $arr as $item->$value ) {
    if( ( $item != $end && $has_started ) || $item == $start) {
      array_push($result, $value);
      $has_started = true;
    }
    if( $item == $end ) {
       array_push($result, $value);
       return $result;
    }
}
$my_values = findValuesBetweenTwoItems($arr, 'EX', 'F');
var_dump($my_values);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'll edit my answer. Btw, there is not a single comment in my code (or other people answering), so quit your macro - or at least an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = array('3X' => '3X','EX'=> 'EX','VG'=>'VG','G'=>'G','F'=>'F','P'=>'P');
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($array);
    $input1 = '3X';
    $input2 = 'F';
    if(in_array($input1,$array) && in_array($input2,$array)) {
        if (array_search($input1, array_keys($array)) >= 0) {
            if (array_search($input2, array_keys($array)) >= 0) {
                if (array_search($input1, array_keys($array)) < array_search($input2, array_keys($array))) {
                    echo "Keys in between: ";
                    for ($i = array_search($input1, array_keys($array)); $i <= array_search($input2, array_keys($array)); $i++) {
                        echo $array[$arrayKeys[$i]] . ", ";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Keys in between: ";
                    for ($i = array_search($input2, array_keys($array)); $i <= array_search($input1, array_keys($array)); $i++) {
                        echo $array[$arrayKeys[$i]] . ", ";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "Value not found!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Value not found!";
        }
    } else{
        echo "Value not found!";
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

```
$from   = 'EX';
$to     = 'F';
$result = null;
$state  = 0;

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
  if (($state == 0 && $from === $v) || ($state == 1 && $to === $v))
    $state++;
  if ($state && $state < 3)
    $result[$k] = $v;
  elseif ($state >= 2)
    break;
}

if ($state != 2)
  $result = null;
```

The loop searches for the first occurrence of `$from`, if `$state` is `0` (initial value), or the first occurrence of `$to`, if `$state` is `1`. For other values of `$state`, the loop stops processing.

When either `$from`, or `$to` is found, `$state` is incremented. The values are stored into `$result` while `$state` is either `1` (`$from` is found), or `2` (`$to` is found).

Thus, `$state == 2` means that both values are found, and `$result` contains the values from the `$a` array between `$from` and `$to`. Otherwise, `$result` is assigned to `null`.